# List of Group of Radio Buttons Struts 2

Tags: jsp, arraylist, struts2, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

I am trying to display the current state(active/inactive) of a particular entity. The no of entities is fetched from the database hence I am using an iterator. For each entity there are 2 radio buttons indicating active/inactive.
I have somehow managed to display the data from the db(not sure if that is the right approach).

Now my problem is this.
1) I need to preselect the state of the entity depending on the value fetched from the database(is_active)
2) If the user makes any changes I need to be able to capture the data in action class in order to save it in the database.
I am using struts-2.3.20.
Appreciate your help.

Action Class

```
private List<Business_bean> list_business = new ArrayList<Business_bean>();


public List<Business_bean> getList_business() {
    return list_business;
}

public void setList_business(List<Business_bean> list_business) {
    this.list_business = list_business;
}


public String execute() {
    try {
        DBconnect obj = new DBconnect();
        String query = "select bid,business_name,is_active from business";
        PreparedStatement ps = obj.conn.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            list_business.add(new Business_bean(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3)));
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
    }
    return "success";
}
```

Bean

```
private String Business_name;
private String Business_id;
private List<String> Business_status;


public Business_bean(String Business_id, String Business_name, String Business_status){
    this.Business_name=Business_name;
    this.Business_id=Business_id;
    this.Business_status=new ArrayList<String>();
    this.Business_status.add("yes");//temp code
    this.Business_status.add("no");//temp code
}

public String getBusiness_name() {
    return Business_name;
}
public void setBusiness_name(String business_name) {
    Business_name = business_name;
}
public String getBusiness_id() {
    return Business_id;
}
public void setBusiness_id(String business_id) {
    Business_id = business_id;
}
public List<String> getBusiness_status() {
    //System.out.println("call getter");
    return Business_status;
}
public void setBusiness_status(List<String> business_status) {
    Business_status = business_status;
}
```

This is my jsp page

```
<form action="">
    <table border="1">
        <!-- loop will fill in the below values -->

        <tr>
            <td>Business Name 1</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="b1" value="true"><input
                type="radio" name="b1" value="false"></td>
        </tr>

        <s:iterator value="list_business" var="obj">
            <tr>
                <td><s:property value="#obj.Business_name" /></td>
                <td><s:radio theme="simple" name="%{Business_id}" list="Business_status" /> </td>
            </tr>
        </s:iterator>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="Submit"
                name="btn_Submit" value="Save Changes" /> <input type="Button"
                name="btn_Cancel" value="Cancel" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a bit of confusion here:

Business_status should be a boolean (or whatever, eg. a String containing "yes" or "no"). 
**It indicates the *state* of *that* entity.**

You should move the list of the possible states outside the entity, eg. in an Enum, or directly in the JSP. **It indicates the possible states assignable to each entity**

Avoid mixing [camelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) and [snake_case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) in variable names. The best practice is to use camelCase only (eg. `businessStatus`).

Once you've adjusted that, if your task will be to populate a page with active / inactive states, and detect any changes made by the user (read: active records set to inactive, and inactive records set to active), I've written a working example to achieve this with checkboxes, feel free to use it or to adapt it to work with radiobuttons:

> [How to get the specifc unchecked checkboxes in Struts2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21827853/1654265)

Comment: what if I check an unchecked box and then uncheck it again. Will it still work?

Comment: No. There are 2 cases: 1) If you need to detect the changes between the original state and the submitted page, then checking and unchecking 1000 times the same element but sending it in its original state won't trigger anything (and it shouldn't); 2) If you need to detect any *user activity* on the page (eg. check and uncheck an unchecked box), then you have to use javascript, because server-side you can only read the delta between what you've sent to the page, and what the page have sent to you