# handle struts unchecked checkbox

Tags: forms, model-view-controller, checkbox, struts2

The fact is that struts will not handle unchecked checkbox.I got a problem.Set the bean type is `InfoForm` and the `recommend` field is associated with a checkbox. In a Controller `A` ,set the `recommend` field with a value 1,means that the checkbox should be checked when load the page. After load the page ,i click the checkbox and set the checkbox to be unchecked. Next,i submit the form to a method in a Controller.But the `recommend` field value will be 1 because the struts checked the checkbox was unchecked status,then will do nothing with it ,and the `recommend` field value passed back to the back end.How can i deal with it?

Comment: Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21827853/1654265

Comment: is not true, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/37045579/573032

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it as this:

```
<script>
$(function () {
$('.ckbox').each(function () {
    var next = $(this).next('input[type="hidden"]');
    if (next.val() == 1)
        this.checked = true;
    else
        this.checked = false;
})
$(".ckbox").bind('change', function () {
    var next = $(this).next('input[type="hidden"]');
    if (this.checked == true)
        next.val(1);
    else
        next.val(0);

})
});
</script>


<input type="checkbox" class="ckbox"/>recommend
<input type="hidden" name="infoBeanForm.recommend" value="${(infoBeanForm.recommend)!0}"/>

<input type="checkbox" class="ckbox"/>
<input type="hidden" name="infoBeanForm.clientType" value="${infoBeanForm.clientType[0]!0}"/>
android
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" class="ckbox"/>
<input type="hidden" name="infoBeanForm.clientType" value="${infoBeanForm.clientType[1]!0}"/>
ios
```